# Perl - How to find the key of a hash if you know the value?

Tags: perl, hash

What I am trying to do is retrieve the key of a key value pair in a hash because all I have from a file I am reading in is a value.

The code produces something like this:

`12345` `welcome.html`

The code for this part is:

```
my %bugs;
my $bug;
open(FH, '-|', "lynx -dump '$queryurl'") or die "Could not lynx $queryurl: $!";
while (<FH>)
{
    if (/<bz:id[^>]*>([^<]*)</)
    {
        $bug = $1;
    }
    if (/<bz:url[^>]*>([^<]*)</)
    {
        my $url = $1;
        $bugs{$url} = $bug;
        $bug = undef;
    }
}
close(FH);

# for debugging purposes
foreach my $bug (keys %bugs)
{
    print "$bugs{$bug} $bug\n";
}
exit;
```

Then, somewhere else in a file called `bad.txt` I get output like:

`Documents that failed:
daerror 6 0 6 welcome.html`

The code for reading this file is :

```
my $badfile = "$dir/bad.txt";
open(FH, "<$badfile") || die "Can not open $badfile: $!";
# ignore first line
<FH>;
while (<FH>)
{
    chomp;
    if (!/^([^ ]+) [^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+ ([^ ]+) [^ ]+$/)
    {
        die "Invalid line $_ in $badfile\n";
    }
    my $type = $1;
    my $testdoc = $2;
}
```

But I already have the filename extracted from this using a regular expression.

Comment: [^ ]+ can also be written as \S+   You can also use `m` and set $type and $testdoc all on one line.  `my($type,$testdoc) = $_ =~ m/^(\S+) \S+ \S+ \S+ (\S+) \S+$/;  die "Invalid line $_ in $badfiles\n" unless defined $type && defined $testdoc;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using the `%bugs` hash for anything else, just modify:

```
$bugs{$url} = $bug;
```

to:

```
$bugs{$bug} = $url;
```

Then you will have a hash with the correct keys to your query needs.

Comment: Or create a new hash, and to handle duplicate values, use an array.

Answer (score 10):

You can make an inverted copy of your original hash with `reverse` operator and then make a "normal" lookup (would work properly only if values in original hash are unique).

More on this topic including handling duplicate values at perlfaq4: [How do I look up a hash element by value](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-look-up-a-hash-element-by-value?)

Comment: thanks for the link, will need to look into it before I accept any answers though!

Answer (score 9):

```
my ($key) = grep{ $bugs{$_} eq '*value*' } keys %bugs;
print $key;
```